# Google Guava Optional - How to short circuit multiple chained expressions

Tags: java, java-8, guava

Suppose I have multiple methods that each return Optional. I want to chain them together so that if one of them returns an Optional with a value then the chain should stop propagation and should stop at that point. e.g. Let's say that f1, f2, f3 each return Optional.

If I do something like this,

```
Optional<T> result = f1.or(f2).or(f3);
```

I see that even if f2 returns an Optional.of(t), f3 still gets called.

I want it to behave like a short circuiting expression but it does not work that way.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Are `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` meant to be `Optional`s? Your question seems to indicate that you are invoking methods but that isn't the case in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a `Supplier` to make it lazy:

```
Stream.<Supplier<Optional<T>>>of(this::f1, this::f2, this::f3)
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .findFirst();
```

Example, in the same vein as Mike's answer:

```
public class LazyOptional {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new LazyOptional().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        Stream.<Supplier<Optional<String>>>of(this::f1, this::f2, this::f3)
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .findFirst();
    }

    public Optional<String> f1() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<String> f2() {
        return Optional.of("a");
    }

    public Optional<String> f3() {
        return Optional.of("b");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Optional.empty
Optional[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a short circuiting stream in Java 8. You can apply a mapping to the result to make the result also come out as an `Optional<T>`, rather than an `Optional<Optional<T>>`.

```
Optional<Integer> e1 = Optional.empty();
Optional<Integer> e2 = Optional.empty();
Optional<Integer> p = Optional.of(1337);
Optional<Integer> e3 = Optional.empty();
Optional<Integer> e4 = Optional.empty();

// peek used to show output
Optional<Integer> first = Stream.of(e1, e2, p, e3, e4)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .findFirst();
```

Output:

```
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
Optional[1337]
```

Comment: My guess is because it's not a guava only answer.